# 19.10: Thunderbolt 3 on ASRock sees connected devices, but can't get those devices to work. They work in Windows

Tags: thunderbolt

I just recently updated my system to an ASRock x570 Creator and installed Ubuntu 19.10 on it. When I go to Thunderbolt in settings I can see my devices, but can't actually make them work.

[image: Thunderbolt Settings]

More specifically, I have a Sonnet Echo Express SE-III PCIe enclosure with a raid card and a Black Magic Intensity in it. However, neither of these work. The highpoint driver doesn't load because it doesn't see a card in the system. And when I open the Black Magic Video desktop app, it also doesn't see the Intensity.

I also have an eGPU that's usually plugged into my Mac Pro, but I decided to give it a shot on the Ubuntu box. Again, the box shows up, in this case a Mantiz Venus, but not the card or any of the other things (SSD, usb, network) on it.

I've tried installing thunderbolt tools, but this didn't seem to do anything.

```
sudo apt-get install -y thunderbolt-tools
```

This is driving me crazy because my previous Ubuntu install on a Asus Prime Deluxe II X299 the thunderbolt and all the attachments just showed up and worked. So, I'm convinced it has to do specifically with ASRock motherboard, but can't seem to find anyone else having the same issues.

I also, booted with a live USB into 20.04 and a few other distributions just to check if it was my distribution, but neither of the devices work in any of them.

UPDATE: I installed Windows just to see if there was something wrong with the motherboard itself. Windows connected immediately and then popped up the devices in the device manager and since I installed the Black Magic Desktop Video driver, it showed present. So I opened the software and it could see it just fine. Likewise for the raid card and the eGPU.

This leads me to believe it is something inside of Ubuntu that isn't allowing the OS to see the devices in the devices. Going to try a fresh install.

UPDATE II: Fresh install of Ubuntu didn't work. I was able to connect and authorize both devices, but still no devices in devices. I also used tbtadm add to add both devices to ACL. Restarted and still not working.

```
   $ tbtadm topology
    Controller 0
        ├─ Details:
        │   ├─ Name: X570 Creator, ASROCK
        │   └─ Security level: SL1 (user)
        │
        ├─ TBX-550CA, TUL
        │   └─ Details:
        │       ├─ Route-string: 0-1
        │       ├─ Authorized: Yes
        │       ├─ In ACL: Yes
        │       └─ UUID: 003670b1-f8dc-6801-ffff-ffffffffffff
        │
        └─ Echo Express SE-III TB3, Sonnet Technologies, Inc.
            └─ Details:
                ├─ Route-string: 0-3
                ├─ Authorized: Yes
                ├─ In ACL: Yes
                └─ UUID: 00cab8e0-2077-0800-ffff-ffffffffffff
```