# Has anyone out there been able to get Thunderbolt 3 to work on an X570?

Tags: thunderbolt

I replaced my Asus X299 rig with an AMD ASRock X570 Creator and can't seem to get Thunderbolt to work completely. I can see the devices connected to Thunderbolt, in this case a Mantiz Venus eGPU and a Sonnet Echo Express III external PCIe expansion chassis, but I don't have access to the cards inside them.

I made a previous post outlining the issues [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223297/thunderbolt-3-on-a-asrock-shows-connected-devices-but-cant-get-those-devices-t), but since no one has answered I'm wondering if it's just me having this problem and if so, I will keep working on it. But if it's an actual issue with Ubuntu and the X570 chipset, or even the Creator specifically, then I can report it as a bug.

Any thoughts would help.

Comment: A search here found no Thunderbird issues on X570 devices. Sometimes answers are slow in coming. Your original post was yesterday.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm just confounded because I also have searched and it doesn't seem like anyone else is having issues. However, I have tried fresh installs, and at least 10 different flavors of Ubuntu, all which fail, yet, Windows, on the same machine, can interact with the devices no problem. Going crazy.

Comment: Take a look at https://egpu.io/forums/builds/2020-asrock-x570-phantom-gaming-itx-tb3ryzen-3400g-9th-4c-a-radeon-vii-32gbps-tb3-razer-core-v2-win10-1909-ningauble77/

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue with PCIe bus number allocation on this chipset and motherboard, [described here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1909360#p1909360). The recommendation (adding `pci=realloc,assign-busses,hpbussize=0x33` to the kernel command line) has worked for me and I was able to connect a Lenovo Thunderbolt 3 dock. However, certain other Thunderbolt devices (e.g. an eGPU) don't work for me on the system, which suggests that something else needs fixing.

EDIT: My current PCIe-related command line is: `pcie_ports=native pci=assign-busses,hpbussize=0x33,realloc,hpmmiosize=256M,hpmmioprefsize=16G`

This makes it possible to connect an NVidia Quadro P5000 inside a Razer Core X Chroma as an eGPU. My forum posts with details and context can be found [on egpu.io](https://egpu.io/forums/postid/90608/), [on ArchLinux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1942723#p1942723), [on NVidia forums](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-quadro-p5000-in-a-razer-core-x-chroma-egpu-fails-to-initialize/160757/4) and [on Razer forums](https://insider.razer.com/index.php?threads/nvidia-quadro-p5000-in-a-razer-core-x-chroma-egpu-fails-to-initialize.66629/#post-697948).

Thunderbolt docks still work and so do Thunderbolt 5k monitors (e.g. LG 27MD5KL, including the built-in USB-C hub, camera and audio device). (One just needs to plug the GPU's DisplayPort outputs into the motherboard's DisplayPort **in**puts meant for Thunderbolt.)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Thunderbolt works but only on cold boot, there is not hot-plug in, it recognizes the devices on hot-plug but they don't work, if you do a full cold boot with the device already connected it will work, but only on the firs port... don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a different laptop (razor blade) and with ubuntu 20.04.2, but had the same (or a very similar) issue with my sonnet echo express SE IIIe.

The box is recognized sometimes right away, sometimes not. A simple

```
lspci
```

on the command line seems to force it to be detected.